# chaostoolkit why do we have create new nodepool for creating chaos

Tags: chaos

I am new to ChaosToolKit, Can someone help me in understanding why do we have create new nodepool as part of creating chaos (Google Cloud Engine) ?

https://docs.chaostoolkit.org/drivers/gce/#create_new_nodepool

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a new node pool. This is an action that can achieve this operation when you want to test the impact of that functionnality against your platform. So, in essence, if you are unsure if adding a new nodepool could degrade your system, this action would help you try that scenario.